# Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP /WEB-INF/views/usuarios/Crud.jsp

Tags: crud

Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP /WEB-INF/views/usuarios/Crud.jsp

```
  code="usuarios.fecha " />:</label>
                            <div class="input-group date datepicker"
                                data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                                <form:input type="text" id="fechaInput" path="fechaFiltro"
                                    class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                                    class="icono-datepicker"></i></span>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.